# OpenSUSE installed alongside Windows 10 doesn't boot after installing Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, btrfs

I installed openSUSE Tumbleweed on my HP probook in dual boot with Windows 10. Then, I noticed some bugs in openSUSE and decided to try Ubuntu 18.04. But after I installed Ubuntu the openSUSE didn't show up in the boot options any more.

I searched for help and found out that I should run some `sudo grub-something` (don't remember what) and the `grub.cfg` was rebuilt and then openSUSE started appearing in the GRUB menu on boot. But when I choose openSUSE in that menu I get an error saying

```
cannot find vmlinuz-5.1.4... Need to load kernel first
```

I tried searching everywhere but have no luck, so I'm here to get a little help.
If you need more details, please, let me know.

EDIT:

I don't know if openSUSE is sharing `/boot` with Ubuntu.

This is the output of `lsblk -o name,fstype,size,label,mountpoint`

```
NAME   FSTYPE     SIZE LABEL MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs 140,7M       /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
loop1  squashfs    13M       /snap/gnome-characters/139
loop2  squashfs  14,5M       /snap/gnome-logs/45
loop3  squashfs   8,4M       /snap/canonical-livepatch/77
loop4  squashfs  34,6M       /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
loop5  squashfs   2,3M       /snap/gnome-calculator/260
loop6  squashfs    91M       /snap/core/6350
loop7  squashfs   3,7M       /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
sda             298,1G       
├─sda1 ntfs       500M       
├─sda2 ntfs     242,1G       
├─sda3              1K       
├─sda4 btrfs       35G       
├─sda5 swap       3,8G       
└─sda6 ext4      16,2G       /
sr0              1024M
```

Comment: Could you open a terminal in Ubuntu, type `lsblk -o name,fstype,size,label,mountpoint` and [edit] your question to paste the output there, please? That should show us your disk partition layout. Do you maybe have a separate `/boot` partition that you shared between Ubuntu and openSUSE?

Comment: Try mounting your btrfs partition and then run sudo update-grub. You may need a btrfs driver installed first to be able to mount it.

Comment: Ive tried both links suggested as duplicate with no success yet

Comment: I've installed the btrfs-progs and did `mkdir /btrfs/` then `mount /dev/sda4 /btrfs` and then `btrfs filesystem df /btfrs/`. Once again `update-grub` but the result was the same.